# Restarting apache is hanging

Tags: php, apache

I am facing a problem that is easy to reproduce: create a PHP file with the code below

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
sleep(100000000);

?>
```

After that access the PHP file you created using your browser and try to restart your server with:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

This line of code hangs for about 50 seconds. After apache restarts I can restart it again in less than 2 seconds.

How can I force a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you: `killall -9 httpd`

After this you have to start the process again.

Comment: isnt there a better solution like "systemctl force-restart httpd.service"?

Comment: @Samul I only know this solution. There might be some others